# res.send and res.render calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to determine if i can call res.send(data) and then res.render('reports') simultaneously.

To explain further in detail, when i route to '/reports', first on my server side i making a REST call to an API which returns back json data. Now i want this json data to be accessed on the client, for which i am making an ajax call from my javascript. Hence the use of res.send(), but i also want to render the page in this call

So it looks like the following on my **server side code**

```
router.get('/reports', function(req,res){
     //Making the REST Call to get the json data
     //then
     res.send(json);
     res.render('reports');
});
```

Every time i hit the '/reports' on the browser, I see the json value instead of the page being rendered and my console throws an Error: **Can't set headers after they are sent.**

Comment: Once you call res.send the response is returned to the client and the connection is closed.

Comment: What is the best technique to get that json value, because i have to render the page once i hit the route

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [content negotiation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.accepts) for that, where your AJAX request sets the `Accept` header to tell your Express server to return JSON instead of HTML:

```
router.get('/reports', function(req,res) {
  ...
  if (req.accepts('json')) {
    return res.send(theData);
  } else {
    return res.render('reports', ...);
  };
});
```

Alternatively, you can check if the request was made with an AJAX call using [`req.xhr`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.xhr) (although that's not 100% failsafe).

Answer (score 7):

No you can't do both, but you could render the page and send the data at the same time:

```
res.render('reports',{data:json});
```

and then access those data in the newly rendered page.

alternatively you could send a flag when making the call , and then decide whether you want to render or send based on this flag.

Comment: i did think of that, but i need to use the ajax as it making use of a plugin that is performing a pagination for me.

Comment: Use the flag, then. if it is a simple call to render the page and there is nothing on your req.query, then render the page
else you could check what's inside the req.query and if has values sent by the ajax call make the res.send

Comment: i do have to render the page from server side, so looks like i cant use res.send(). Could you tell me what are the alternatives for my ajax to access the json data?

Comment: what do you mean? You could get into another route so that in each route you get what you want. eg router.get("/report_json",function(req,res){}); but i am not sure if it continues to be rest.

Comment: actually you were right to keep a flag, I just kept a flag based on req.headers.accept to send the json or render the page. So that solved the problem. Thanks! again appreciate the help

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, it needs to be 2 separate route, one spitting json and other rendering a view. Else, you could pass a url param, depending on which you return json or render a view.

```
router.get('/reports/json', function(req,res){
   var data = JSON_OBJECT;
   res.send(data);
});

router.get('/reports', function(req,res){
   var data = JSON_OBJECT;
   res.render('path-to-view-file', data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. You can only have a single response to a given request. The browser is either expecting an HTML document or it is expecting JSON, it doesn't make sense to give it both at once.

`render` just renders a view and then calls `send`.

You could write your view to output an HTML document with a `<script>` element containing your JSON in the form of a JavaScript literal.